# Why does ping wait 1 second for the next ping?

Tags: ubuntu, ping

On Ubuntu 20.04.4 I am running a `ping` command like

```
sudo ping -l 2000 -c 200  domain.com
```

and it does the first 12 pings immediately, but then only 1 ping after the other ping with a delay of 1 second.

To be precise: I get an output like this

```
64 bytes from my.domain.com (1.2.3.4): icmp_seq=65 ttl=62 time=0.392 ms
64 bytes from my.domain.com (1.2.3.4): icmp_seq=66 ttl=62 time=0.398 ms
```

and each line (`icmp_seq`) is one second apart. So for the 200 pings to complete I have to wait approx. 200 seconds.

I noticed that when I run the command on `localhost` or on a Mac all the 200 pings run within a second, without the wait between the individual pings.

What is the reason for this behavior? Is there any way to run the ping command faster?

Comment: `ping` on Linux has two options that may do what you want. `-f` sends out a new ping as soon as the last one is received. `-i interval` sets a specific wait time between pings. BSD ping has the same options so I don't know why a Mac does it differently.

Comment: I got the same effect on Debian. Even curiouser: if I run it under strace, it seems to send all the requests just fine, and after that, the sequence numbers match what would be packets sent after that initial burst. Unlike what seemed to happen to you.

Comment: @doneal24, `-l 2000` is supposed to send 2000 packets without waiting for replies, and by implication, I think it should do that as fast as it can. And it does that for me, but only under strace...

Comment: I'm running Arch Linux, and for me, only the first eight happen immediately, but I get a message saying `ping: WARNING: probably, rcvbuf is not enough to hold preload`

Comment: @ilkkachu Interesting is that with `-f -c 1000` I get a response time of 182ms and 0% packet loss. Using `-l 1000 0-c 1000` it takes only 25ms but with 80% packet loss. Doesn't change under strace. I'm also seeing the `rcvbuf` error frequently. This is on a 10Gb network, physical servers, same vlan.

Comment: On Debian 11 (but with kernel 5.17.x), as root with ping from the package iputils-ping (not inetutils-ping), `ping -l 2000 -c 200 127.0.0.1` behaves as expected: all 200 packets are sent within the second. inetutils-ping's ping behaves strangely (it appears it loses replies). Anyway it seems the behavior varies depending on some factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is the reason for this behavior?

The basic issue with ping speed is that it may **flood** any connection and cause a DOS over that connection. To ease (avoid) such problem, `ping` is limited to produce (send) **one** packet per second by default.

The `-l` option is not meant to control the time it takes for packets to be sent. It is used to *pre***L***oad* the network. I.e.: it is the number of packets that would be sent to the network initially without waiting for a reply. After that, the default time of 1-second is used to sent packets for each (detected) packet received back (response). However that preLoad is limited for normal users. The number of preloaded packets is limited to 3 for a normal user. With iputils-ping version `20210202` we can add a `-D` to see the time of each packet sent:

```
$ sudo ping -c 5   -l 3   -D   127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[1655501483.063447] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms
[1655501483.063488] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
[1655501483.063510] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms
[1655501484.094896] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.156 ms
[1655501485.065238] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.153 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.017/0.095/0.156/0.063 ms, pipe 3
```

Which shows that only 3 packets are sent ASAP and the rest waits 1 second.

That's using the local address `127.0.0.1`. Which is the fastest address that could be used, as it is entirely **local**.

Resolving some other address, or even worse, a domain, may introduce additional delays.

A preload of 2000 over 200 packets would preload all of them leading to no delay in sending and only the delay of the answer will matter.

### Is there any way to run the ping command faster?

But all the above is not the correct way to control the speed at which packets are sent.

#### -i

For that there are the two options `-i`:

```
$ sudo ping -D -c 5 -i 0.2 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[1655501954.082366] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.131 ms
[1655501954.286594] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.151 ms
[1655501954.490564] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.127 ms
[1655501954.694608] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.147 ms
[1655501954.898607] 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.151 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 816ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.127/0.141/0.151/0.010 ms
```

That is a constant speed ping command. Note that even for the local address it takes a bit more than 0.13 ms to get a response. As a general rule, pinging with times lower than 0.1 seconds is not recommended.

#### -f

And the option `-f` which is used exactly to **flood** the network as fast as possible. But which will certainly block any other process using it.

### Why

In fact, the question should be: why do you want a fast ping?.

Just to have the fastest answer?

That is not really useful as the intent of `ping` is to test the network over some period of time, a reasonable period of time, to ensure that the network is stable and useful. A "too fast" test will test the network at only one point in time (in which the network is working) but will fail to detect problems over time (the network might fail). Besides, it affects other users of the same network. If you want a "one time only" test, then use the `-c count` option combined with the `-w delay` option which will end after   either count packets have been received or delay has been elapsed:

```
$ sudo ping -D -c 3 -w 5 example.com ; echo "$?"

$ sudo ping -D -c 3 -w 5 examples.com ; echo "$?"
```

The first one will count 3 packets and exit successfully.
The second one will fail after 5 seconds.

That is one correct way to test connectivity.

Comment: yes, that's what preload does. But the weird thing is that with e.g. `-l 200`, it sometimes shows e.g. 42 replies received immediately, with the next ones coming a second apart, with sequence numbers 43, 44, 45 etc. as if the rest of the preload burst wasn't sent at all. And `-D` shows those timings. It's like as if you set `-l 10` in your example instead, but still got the same results as in your actual example with `-l 3`. I don't see this answer addressing that at all. (plus limits for a regular user shouldn't matter since they ran it under `sudo` anyway.)

Comment: @ilkkachu You are free to guess what could be the reason for the weird behavior and post a beter answer.

Comment: @ilkkachu I have not been able to reproduce the odd behavior, so, I could not dig any deeper. But if you are reporting a problem it would be wise to say on which OS and with which version of ping at the very minimum.